# Creating DLL from CUDA using nvcc

Tags: dll, cuda, nvcc

I want to create a .dll from a CUDA code (`kernel.cu`) in order to use this library from an external C program. After some attempts I just left a simple C function in .cu file. Code follows:

kernel.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kernel.h"

void hello(const char *s) {
        printf("Hello %s\n", s);
}/*
```

kernel.h

```
#ifndef KERNEL_H
#define KERNEL_H

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void __declspec(dllexport) hello(const char *s);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // KERNEL_H
```

I tried to first generate a `kernel.o` object with `nvcc` and after i used `g++` for creating DLL as following:

```
nvcc -c kernel.cu -o kernel.o
g++ -shared -o kernel.dll kernel.o -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\lib\x64" -lcudart
```

It works fine and generates `kernel.dll`. To test DLL file I wrote this simple program `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void __declspec ( dllimport ) hello(const char *s);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int main(void) {
        hello("World");
        return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
g++ -o app.exe main.c -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include" -L. -lkernel
```

Result is a memory access error when execution starts.

Nevertheless, if I rename .cu file in .c (as it is just C code), using the same commands, it does work. nvcc's output changes, as far as I know because it uses default C compiler instead of CUDA one.

What do you think, is it a problem related with nvcc? Or am I making any mistake?

**EDIT**: I forgot some info which may be important. Warnings appear in the first call to g++ (when dll is created) and they are different depending on whether .cu .c or .cpp.

.cu

```
Warning: .drectve `/FAILIFMISMATCH:"_MSC_VER=1600" /FAILIFMISMATCH:"_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0" 
/DEFAULTLIB:"libcpmt" /DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" /EXPORT:hello ' unrecognized
```

and it doesn't work.

.cpp and .c

```
Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" /EXPORT:hello ' unrecognized
```

and it works.

Comment: What happens if you rename the .cu file to .cpp instead of .c does it still work?

Comment: Works fine for me on Linux (well, without `dllimport` and with `-fPIC`). When I use the verbose mode (`nvcc -v`), I can see that `nvcc` calls `gcc` in C++ mode by default (`gcc -x c++ ...`).

Comment: @Robert It works with .cpp also.

Comment: I realized I had forgotten about Warnings. Question is edited now.

Comment: So, you're apparently using CUDA 5.0. What is your `g++` version?

Comment: @BenC Yes, CUDA 5.0. g++ is a Windows x64 personal-build downloaded from MinGW site:
`g++ (rubenvb-4.8.0) 4.8.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: The only officially supported C/C++ compiler on windows platforms is cl.exe, the compiler that ships with MS Visual Studio.  I believe many folks have been successful building DLLs with the MS VS setup.  You can get a free version using any of the MS VS express products.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved. I still don't know why happened (maybe it is because of not using *official* compiler like Robert Crovella said), but replacing the two commands for making a DLL by this one works:

```
nvcc -o kernel.dll --shared kernel.cu
```

Note the double dash (nvcc works this way), and the fact of making it directly instead of creating first `.o` and then making DLL from the object.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio you can also make it compile into a .dll instead of a .obj file by navigating through the options:

> DEBUG -> -*Project name*- Properties -> Configuration properties -> Configuration Type

Change the option from Application(.exe) to Dynamic Library(.dll)

You can find the dll after compiling in the DEBUG folder or RELEASE folder

Comment: The project still produces only exe even after I choose dll.

Comment: This worked for me, except for  some reason the dll was output into a folder at the same level as the solution file