# Using cusp in a Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, cusp-library

I'm using cusp v.0.4.0, cuda V5.5 on VS2012 Ultimate. I created a CUDA project using the new project wizard and added the cusp path to it's **project properties\VC++ Directories\Include Directories**. I wrote my code in the ***.cu** file generated by VS2012, the project compiled and built successfully but I got **R6010** error on execution. I solved this issue by changing the default value of **project properties\CUDA C/C++\Device\Code Generation** from **compute_10,sm_10** to **compute_30,sm_30**, which is my sm version. Everything worked well.

Now I want to use the same code in a C++ project. When I added it to a new C++ project and I added the cusp path to **VC++ Include Directories**, the project build failed with numerous syntax errors in several files:

> Error  5   error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'    c:\users\administrator\downloads\android\cusplibrary-master\cusplibrary-master\cusp\detail\device\spmv\coo_flat.h   164
>
> 22 IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Android\cusplibrary-master\cusplibrary-master\cusp\detail\device\spmv\coo_flat.h   272
>
> ...

There are 108 more errors like these. If these are syntax errors, why didn't any of them show up in my CUDA solution? How can I successfully build my code in a C++ project?

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <cusp/krylov/cg.h>
#include <cusp/csr_matrix.h>
#include <cusp/hyb_matrix.h>
#include <cusp/gallery/poisson.h>
#include <cusp/io/matrix_market.h>
#include <cusp\print.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int N = 10000;
    int nnz = 1005070;
    DWORD dw1 = GetTickCount();
    cusp::csr_matrix<int,double,cusp::device_memory> A(N,N,nnz);
    DWORD dw2 = GetTickCount();
    double dw3 = dw2 - dw1;
    cout << "alocating A matrix time : " << dw3 << endl;

    ifstream rowOffseFile;
    ifstream colIndexFile;
    ifstream valuesFile;
    ifstream ansFile;

    rowOffseFile.open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\MATLAB\\10000_0.01_RO.txt");
    int *rowOffset = NULL;
    rowOffset = (int *)malloc((N+1)*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < N+1; i++)
    {
        rowOffset[i] = 0;
    }
    int i =0;
    if (rowOffseFile.is_open()) {
        while (!rowOffseFile.eof()) {
            rowOffseFile >> rowOffset[i];
            i+=1;
        }
    }
    rowOffseFile.close();
    DWORD dw10 = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < (N+1); i++)
    {
        A.row_offsets[i] = rowOffset[i];
    }
    DWORD dw11 = GetTickCount();
    double dw12 =dw11 - dw10;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    colIndexFile.open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\MATLAB\\10000_0.01_CI.txt");
    int *colIndex = NULL;
    colIndex = (int *)malloc((nnz)*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; i++)
    {
        colIndex[i] = 0;
    }
    i =0;
    if (colIndexFile.is_open()) {
        while (!colIndexFile.eof()) {
            colIndexFile >> colIndex[i];
            //int temp = (int)output;
            //cout<< colIndex[i] << endl;
            i+=1;
        }
    }
    colIndexFile.close();
    DWORD ex1 = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; i++)
    {
        A.column_indices[i] = colIndex[i];
    }
    DWORD ex2 = GetTickCount();
    double t = ex2-ex1;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    valuesFile.open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\MATLAB\\10000_0.01_V.txt");
    double *values = NULL;
    values = (double *)malloc((nnz)*sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; i++)
    {
        values[i] = 0;
    }
    i =0;
    if (valuesFile.is_open()) {
        while (!valuesFile.eof()) {
            valuesFile >> values[i];
            //int temp = (int)output;
            //cout<< colIndex[i] << endl;
            i+=1;
        }
    }
    valuesFile.close();
    DWORD ex3 = GetTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; i++)
    {
        A.values[i] = values[i];
    }
    DWORD ex4 = GetTickCount();
    t = t+ex4-ex3+dw12;
    cout << "time spent on initializing: " << t <<endl;

    DWORD dw7 = GetTickCount();
    cusp::array1d<double,cusp::device_memory> X(N,0.);
    cusp::array1d<double,cusp::device_memory> B(N,1.);
    DWORD dw8 = GetTickCount();
    double dw9 = dw8-dw7;
    cout << "time spent on allocating X and B :" << dw9 << endl;
    DWORD dw4 = GetTickCount();

    cusp::krylov::cg(A,X,B);
    DWORD dw5 = GetTickCount();
    double dw6 = dw5 - dw4;
    std::cout << "time spenton solving : " << dw6 << std::endl;
    //cusp::print(X);

    ansFile.open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\MATLAB\\10000_0.01_X.txt");
    double *ans = NULL;
    ans = (double *)malloc((N)*sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        ans[i] = 0;
    }

    i =0;
    if (ansFile.is_open()) {
        while (!ansFile.eof()) {
            ansFile >> ans[i];
            //int temp = (int)output;
            //cout<< rowOffset[i] << endl;
            i+=1;
        }
    }
    ansFile.close();

    double tol = 0;
    double temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        temp = abs(X[i] - ans[i]);
        if (temp>tol)
        {
            tol = temp;
        }
    }
    cout << "max tol is :" << tol << endl;

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Now I want to use this piece of code in a written Project in C++, but when I added that very same code to a new C++ project ... "

That probably won't work. If this code is in a .cpp in a C++ project, it won't work.

cusp is a template library that is built on top of thrust which is built on top of CUDA, so cusp codes *must* be compiled by `nvcc`, i.e. it must be in a CUDA project in VS, not an ordinary C++ project.

So go back to using a CUDA project in VS for your cusp codes.

Comment: oh my god... there is no way at all? can't even make a static or dynamic library from it and link it to the project?

Comment: cusp codes need to be compiled by `nvcc`.  That will happen in a relatively straightforward fashion in a CUDA project.  Yes, if you create a static or dynamic library, that may be another way, although a static library may still present some challenges.  Ceratinly a DLL is doable.  You can also call your cusp codes via wrapper functions from your C++ project, i.e. create a VS solution with multiple projects, one of which is a C++ and one of which is a CUDA project.

Comment: dear robert thank you so much, second way you suggested seems to be easy however would you please show me a tutorial or illustration on creating a DLL containing cusp? thank you for your precious time

Comment: There shouldn't be anything specific to cusp, i.e. if you search on how to make a CUDA DLL you'll get plenty of ideas, such as [this one on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423643/creating-dll-from-cuda-using-nvcc) which is pretty simple, to this [tutorial](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/hot-rodding-windows-and-linux-app-perfor/232601605)