# using a template function as dll in another project

Tags: c++, dll

I have a simple function like this:

**cusp.dll**

```
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
EXPORT 
void cuspDsolver(int *r, int *c, double *v, double *x, double *b, int size, int nnz,double tol)
{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

and I created a dll using these two lines:

```
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
EXPORT
```

and I called this function in other Project using this method:

```
HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Visual Studio           2012\\Projects\\Ardalan_12\\cusp.dll");
if(hDLL == NULL)
{
    cout<< "Failed to load DLL" <<endl;
}

typedef void(*fnPtr)(int *, int *, double *, double *, double *, int , int ,double);

fnPtr pfn;

pfn=(fnPtr)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"cuspDsolver");

if(pfn)
{
    pfn(rowOffset,colIndex,values,answer,rightHandSide,theSize,nnz,0.9);
}

FreeLibrary(hDLL);
```

this works very fine, but now I changed my function to this

```
//#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
//EXPORT 
template <typename LinearOperator,typename Vector>
void cuspDsolver(LinearOperator& A,Vector& X,Vector& B,double tol)
{

    cusp::default_monitor<double> monitor(B, 10000, tol);
    cusp::precond::scaled_bridson_ainv<double,cusp::device_memory> PRE(A);
    DWORD dw1 = GetTickCount();
    cusp::krylov::cg(A,X,B,monitor,PRE);
    DWORD dw2 = GetTickCount();
    double dw3 = dw2 - dw1;
    cout <<endl << "time spent is : " << dw3 << endl;
    cout << endl << "developed by cusp!!!"  << endl;
}
```

but Visual Studio won't allow **extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)** with **template functions** is there any way to do this easily?actually I'm not expert,so would you please explain this to me in detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "template function." There is a *function template,* however; that is a template from which functions are created by instantiation. In this case, the distinction is important.

To call a function instantiated from a template, you must have access to that instantiation. The most common case is to implement the template in a header file and simply `#include` it (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1782465) for more details). I believe that you want your function to be usable with arbitrary client-supplied types as `LinearOperation` and `Vector`, so a header-only implementation is your only option.

---

If, on the other hand, you know all the types you would want to instantiate the template with when building your library, you can actually *explicitly instantiate* the template for those types and export these explicit instantiations. Like this:

**Header file**

```
template <typename LinearOperator,typename Vector>
void cuspDsolver(LinearOperator& A,Vector& X,Vector& B,double tol);
```

**Source file**

```
template <typename LinearOperator,typename Vector>
void cuspDsolver(LinearOperator& A,Vector& X,Vector& B,double tol)
{
  // body here
}

template __declspec(dllexport) void cuspDsolver(MyConcreteOperator1& A, MyConcreteVector1& X, MyConcreteVector1& B, double tol);
template __declspec(dllexport) void cuspDsolver(MyConcreteOperator2& A, MyConcreteVector2& X, MyConcreteVector2& B, double tol);
// etc.
```

Such instantiations cannot be `extern "C"`, however (they all have the same function name, after all). So if you want to load them dynamically, you'll have to provide uniquely-named C-linkage accessors to them.

Still, I believe what you're really looking for is implementing the funciton in a header file.

---

Based on your comments, here is how you could actually make your library dynamically loadable while using CUSP internally.

You cannot have a function template in your library's public interface. So let's say you want to allow using your library with the following types of `LinearOperator`: `OperatorCharm` and `OperatorTop`, and with the following types of `Vector`: `FancyVector<float>` and `FancyVector<double>`. Then, your public interface could look like this:

```
template <typename LinearOperator,typename Vector>
void cuspDsolver(LinearOperator& A,Vector& X,Vector& B,double tol)
{
  // body
}


EXPORT void cuspDsolver_Charm_float(params_which, correspond_to, OperatorCharm_and, FancyVector_of_float)
{
  cuspDsolver(params);
}

EXPORT void cuspDsolver_Charm_double(params_which, correspond_to, OperatorCharm_and, FancyVector_of_double)
{
  cuspDsolver(params);
}

EXPORT void cuspDsolver_Top_float(params_which, correspond_to, OperatorTop_and, FancyVector_of_float)
{
  cuspDsolver(params);
}

EXPORT void cuspDsolver_Charm_double(params_which, correspond_to, OperatorTop_and, FancyVector_of_double)
{
  cuspDsolver(params);
}
```

You don't even have to instantiate the template explicitly any more, since it will be instantiated implicitly for the calls in the `EXPORT`-ed functions.

So in effect, your public API will be those 4 `cuspDsolver_a_b` functions, which can be queried dynamically as normal.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer however my function uses **CUSP** library and it has to compiled with **nvcc** but my other project is  **VC++** I suppose I cannot include it, would you explain the second way a little bit more or reference me to a link that helps me to understand what your purpose is?

Comment: @user3297741 I don't really see why you couldn't link CUSP into a VS project. The CUDA SDK contains VS integration for CUDA files, after all. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: actually I don't know either but here [Using cusp in a Visual Studio C++ project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942540/using-cusp-in-a-visual-studio-c-project) says so.

Comment: @user3297741 OK, I wasn't aware CUSP was template-only. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: Dear @Angew Thank you so much, I'm confused with your notation would you give me an example(I don'n know what do you mean by:`(params_which, correspond_to, OperatorCharm_and, FancyVector_of_float)` and `(params)`?

Comment: @user3297741 Here is a [mock example](http://ideone.com/pVQPxi). I hope it's clearer now. I don't know how the parameters `r`, `c`, `v` etc. in your original post correspond to `A`, `X`, `B` etc., so I couldn't write a more precise example.

Comment: I guess you miss understood my code **LinearOperator** is not an example it is a class I mean it is not ***plus*** or ***minus*** it is a class it self which declared in a header file of ***CUSP***.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48352/discussion-between-angew-and-user3297741)

Answer (score 1):

Template functions are not compiled and thus not part of a DLL as there's an infinite number of function derived from a template.

Only specific instances of the template are compiled and linked into a binary. You can expose those specialized template functions in a DLL. You'll need a header file for those names as string them in a hardcoded string is problematic.

If you want to use a template function w/o specializing it, export it through a header file.

Comment: thanks but there is another problem a cannot include header files, because it's from cusp library and have to compiled with **nvcc** but my project is **VC++**, is there any other way to do this? can I illustrate **typename LinearOperator** to compiler any other way than template?